# EF .NET Core2 first time loading takes more time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, delayed-execution

We have developed EF .NET Core2 application with 600+ model classes. A lot of DBContext classes are there. DB is available in AWS environment. No local database was available. We are accessing EF through webAPI. when we hit API for the first time, it takes around 3 to 4 minutes to load. Second time onwards, it loads within 4 seconds as expected. What are the ways I can reduce the loading time. The main problem is for developers. They are fixing the bugs. Each and every time they are waiting for 3 minutes to load while working on the issue.
Also, we used ITextsharper for PDF work.

We Disabled the trackchanges.

```
//Adding DbContext
services.AddDbContext<EPMSDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EPMSDB1")));
services.AddTransient(typeof(EPMS.Services.Authentication.IAuthenticationService), typeof(EPMS.Services.Authentication.AuthenticationService));
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

it must load within 30 seconds during the first time load.

Comment: Are you using virtual properties for your relations in models?

Comment: No. We are using Model First approach.

Comment: Is it the context initialisation that takes 4 minutes or the first query?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9347

Comment: First query takes 4 minutes to show the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first time is slower because EF is configuring table mappings and the context. That is something that will always happen, but you can reduce it by optimizing you dbcontext, and there are several approaches, one of them is to split your db context into several db context with specific entities, this way is not so heavy for the application to start.

Answer (score 0):

## EF6

You can pre-prepare Entity Framework by calling `Initalize`.

```
using( var context = (...) )
{
 context.Database.Initialize(force: false); 
}
```

---

## EF Core

In EF Core `DatabaseFacade` does not provide `Initialise()` and I cannot find antything like that in [`RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions?view=efcore-3.0).

You can still do a worm up query.

---

### What's loaded

BTW. This is what the first creation of DBContext reports in .NET Core 3.0 with an SQLite provider.

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\EFGetStarted.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Runtime.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\netstandard.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Console.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Threading.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. 
.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Collections.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Linq.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. 
Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'.
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Data.Common.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Transactions.Local.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. 
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10409]
      An additional 'IServiceProvider' was created for internal use by Entity Framework. An existing service provider was not used due to the following configuration changes: configuration added for 'Core:UseMemoryCache', configuration added for 'Core:EnableSensitiveDataLogging', configuration added for 'Core:EnableDetailedErrors', configuration added for 'Core:ConfigureWarnings', configuration added for 'Sqlite'.
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Private.Uri.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. 
Loaded '...\3.0.0\System.ObjectModel.dll'. 
Loaded '...\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. 
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'BloggingContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
```